# Efficient method of importing values from React to CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been looking at some different options for a method of sharing/importing values from a React component to a Sass/CSS file. I have the `background` property of a component being set after receiving props that contain a path to an image (from an API). This is set as an inline style.

I also want to add an opaque layer to the component image **on hover**. This is easily accomplished with regular CSS, however I can't simply overwrite the `background` property to a gradient or color when hovered over.

I need to also fetch the image path being used in the component's inline style in order to apply the opacity **over** the image.

Component:

```
render() {
    const styles = {
      background: `url('...somepath.jpeg') no-repeat center`
    }
    const item = { ...type, ...this.props.metadata };

    return (
      <section className="card"
               onClick={this.props.cb.bind(null, item)}
               style={styles}>
      </section>
    );
  }
```

Styles:

```
.card:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(20,20,20, .5), rgba(20,20,20, .5)) !important;
        // without the path to build the url, this just deletes the image
 }
```

Basically the style I'm looking to apply on hover would appear like this:
`linear-gradient(rgba(20,20,20, .5), rgba(20,20,20, .5)), url('...somepath.jpeg') no-repeat center`

Is there an efficient method to accomplish something like this? I could only think of adding mouseover/mouseout event listeners to the component to add "hover" inline styles... but I want to stay way from using inline too much.

Comment: Why cannot `css` be utilized?

Comment: @guest271314 The path to the image is coming from an API call who's response is being passed down as props to this card component. I can't find a way to import that path into a CSS file. Inline styles don't support pseudo-selectors either.

Comment: You can set a `css` rule at an existing `CSSStyleSheet` or append `css` text to a `<style>` element in `document`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components). With styled components you can pass down a url as a prop, while still being able to use the full power of CSS.

Sample code specific to your case:

```
const Section = styled.section`
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    ${(props) => `background: url(${props.url}) no-repeat center` }
  }
`

render() {
  const item = { ...type, ...this.props.metadata };

  return (
    <Secion className="card"
             onClick={this.props.cb.bind(null, item)}
             url="...somepath.jpeg"
     />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting solution to the problem. However, are you ever concerned that this library is basically more inline styling? I've been told to avoid using inline styles when possible (although I can't say for sure why that may be).

Comment: @Jose this library has almost all functionality that is available through SASS (pseudo classes, media queries, etc.). It's definitely different from plain inline styles.

Comment: This is pretty cool. What about concerns over maintaining styles inside React components **and** stylesheets? Wouldn't that scatter styling even more amid different files?

Comment: @Jose in theory you should keep all your styles inside the component and have very few global styles.